# How can we use LocationRequest.Builder in requestLocationUpdates() function as a parameter

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, user-permissions

As LocationRequest.create() is deprecated and instead of it we shall use LocationRequest.Builder but when i pass this in requestLocationUpdates() as a parameter, it shows error.

Here's my code:

```
private boolean isLocationpermissionOk;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
```

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
private void setUpLocationUpdate() {
    locationRequest= new LocationRequest.Builder(10000).build();
    locationCallback=new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            if(locationResult!=null) {
                for(Location location : locationResult.getLocations()){
                    Log.d("TAG","onLocationResult"+location.getLongitude()+" "+location.getLatitude());
                }
            }
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

        }
    };
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Location Updated Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: `when i pass this in requestLocationUpdates() as a parameter, it shows error` , what error does it show?

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(android.location.LocationRequest, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback, android.os.Looper)'

Comment: First parameter should be of type `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest`.  This  means you are using the wrong builder - use `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.Builder` .